# Get specific item from canvas using rcptt tool

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcptt

I am exploring rcptt tool to automate our RCP based application GUI.

I found one problem here. For canvas, it shows only the coordinate and height width.

While recording, rcptt gives the below code

```
with [get-editor "graph-editor" | get-canvas] {

    get-figure -path "0/34" | mouse-enter 370 136 -height 104 -width 303
    mouse-move 443 275 -height 506 -width 1453
    mouse-exit 447 257 -height 506 -width 1453
}
```

But this coordinate is not always same.
I want to get the specific node  or specific item from that canvas but no suggestion found.

Also in this link: http://download.xored.com/q7/docs/ecl-api/latest#get-canvas 
they used coordinated as example.

Need suggestion on this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's all RCPTT can do; it's a technical limit you're facing.

The most you can do to stabilize tests is to [maximize](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/faq/resize-window/) the window, and make sure that there are enough screen pixels on your (virtual)machine to display all logic at once. RCPTT will not scroll the canvas to find an element.